# Serilog logs to console but not to file

Tags: c#, serilog

I have the below logger configuration and associated classes as below. The expected log messages are below:

```
2019-03-06 19:49:56.417 +05:30 [INFORMATION] [Main] Start
2019-03-06 19:49:56.435 +05:30 [INFORMATION] [Test1] Test1 logg
```

I see both the log messages in console. But I see only the first log in the file.

```
namespace SerilogTest
{
    public static class MyLogger
    {
        public static ILogger getLogger(String className)
        {
            string logTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: logTemplate)
                .WriteTo.File("log.txt", outputTemplate: logTemplate)
                .CreateLogger()
                .ForContext("SourceContext", className);

            return Log.Logger;
        }    
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static ILogger Log = MyLogger.getLogger("Main");

        private static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Log.Information("Start");
            Test1 t1 = new Test1();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Test1
    {
        private static ILogger Log = MyLogger.getLogger(typeof(Test1).Name);

        public Test1()
        {
            Log.Information("Test1 logg");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You should ensure you call `Log.CloseAndFlush();` before closing the application, because the writing to file is not immediate

Comment: Is there any way to automatically log to file say every second?  I wanted to deploy a service and wanted to monitor the log file while it is running.

Comment: Use the `flushToDiskInterval` parameter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to enable multi-process shared log files, set `shared` to `true`

```
.WriteTo.File("log.txt", outputTemplate: logTemplate, shared: true)
```

Also no need to crate logger each time you need to log, Just create it one time on application start and use it everywhere in your application (Check below example).

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    public static void CreateLogger()
    {
        String logTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}";
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: logTemplate)
            .WriteTo.File("log.txt", outputTemplate: logTemplate)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        MyLogger.CreateLogger();

        Log.ForContext("SourceContext", "Main").Information("Start");
        Test1 t1 = new Test1();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Test1
{
    public Test1()
    {
        Log.ForContext("SourceContext", typeof(Test1).Name).Information("Test1 logg");

    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.